# Java Beans, BeanUtils, and the Boolean wrapper class

Tags: java, jaxb, javabeans, apache-commons-beanutils

I'm using BeanUtils to manipulate Java objects created via JAXB, and I've run into an interesting issue.  Sometimes, JAXB will create a Java object like this:

```
public class Bean {
    protected Boolean happy;

    public Boolean isHappy() {
        return happy;
    }

    public void setHappy(Boolean happy) {
        this.happy = happy;
    }
}
```

The following code works just fine:

```
Bean bean = new Bean();
BeanUtils.setProperty(bean, "happy", true);
```

However, attempting to get the `happy` property like so:

```
Bean bean = new Bean();
BeanUtils.getProperty(bean, "happy");
```

Results in this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Property 'happy' has no getter method in class 'class Bean'
```

Changing everything to a primitive `boolean` allows both the set and get call to work.  I don't have this option, however, since these are generated classes.  I assume this happens because the Java Bean libraries only consider an `is<name>` method to represent a property if the return type is a primitive `boolean`, and not the wrapper type `Boolean`.  Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to access properties like these through BeanUtils?  Is there some kind of workaround I can use?

Comment: Where does the `BeanUtils` class come from? I checked with `org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils` (1.8.3) and it works fine. Please note that typically `is` prefix is used for `boolean`, while for `Boolean`: `get`.

Comment: I'm using the same BeanUtils.  You were able to do a `getProperty()` with an `is` method that returns the `Boolean` wrapper class?

Comment: Your assumption about is<name> is correct. isXXX only applys to type boolean return type. For Boolean return type, getXXX is the correct method name.

Comment: you're right, `getProperty()` does not work with `Boolean is`. In fact, IntelliJ generates getters with `get` for `Boolean` and `is` for `boolean` - I guess Eclipse does the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I've found legal confirmation:

> #### 8.3.2 Boolean properties
>
> In addition, for boolean properties, we allow a getter method to match the pattern:
>
> `public boolean is<PropertyName>();`

From *JavaBeans specification*. Are you sure you haven't came across [JAXB-131](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-131) bug?

Comment: Yep, looks like I was running into that bug.  I upgraded my JAXB version to 2.1.13 and added the "-enableIntrospection" flag.  That changed all the `Boolean` wrapper `is` methods to `get`s.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

**Workaround to handle Boolean isFooBar() case with BeanUtils**

1. Create new BeanIntrospector

---

```
private static class BooleanIntrospector implements BeanIntrospector{
    @Override
    public void introspect(IntrospectionContext icontext) throws IntrospectionException {
        for (Method m : icontext.getTargetClass().getMethods()) {
            if (m.getName().startsWith("is") && Boolean.class.equals(m.getReturnType())) {
                String propertyName = getPropertyName(m);
                PropertyDescriptor pd = icontext.getPropertyDescriptor(propertyName);

                if (pd == null)
                    icontext.addPropertyDescriptor(new PropertyDescriptor(propertyName, m, getWriteMethod(icontext.getTargetClass(), propertyName)));
                else if (pd.getReadMethod() == null)
                    pd.setReadMethod(m);

            }
        }
    }

    private String getPropertyName(Method m){
        return WordUtils.uncapitalize(m.getName().substring(2, m.getName().length()));
    }

    private Method getWriteMethod(Class<?> clazz, String propertyName){
        try {
            return clazz.getMethod("get" + WordUtils.capitalize(propertyName));
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

---

1. Register BooleanIntrospector:

   BeanUtilsBean.getInstance().getPropertyUtils().addBeanIntrospector(new BooleanIntrospector());

Comment: Good stuff! I think there are 2 changes needed though: in getWriteMethod, it should be "set" - and also, I was getting MethodNotFoundExceptions until I changed to the overloaded method that receives a parameter type: `return clazz.getMethod("set" + WordUtils.capitalize(propertyName), Boolean.class);`

Answer (score 0):

you can just create second getter with SET - sufix as workaround :)