# dozer Boolean property mapping

Tags: java, groovy, dozer

It appears that Dozer will not map a Boolean property if the accessor of that property is defined as `isProperty()` rather than `getProperty()`.

The following groovy script illustrates the problem:

```
import org.dozer.*

class ProductCommand {
    Boolean foo 
}

public class ProductDto  {

    private Boolean foo;        

    public Boolean isFoo() { this.foo }    
    public void setFoo(Boolean p0) { this.foo = p0 }           
}

def mapper =  new DozerBeanMapper()

dto = new ProductDto(foo: true)
assert dto.isFoo()

ProductCommand mappedCmd = mapper.map(dto, ProductCommand)
assert mappedCmd.foo
```

The assertion on the final line fails. However, if I rename `ProductDto.isFoo()` to `ProductDto.getFoo()` it passes.

Is there a flag/option I can set in the Dozer mapping file that will instruct it to use either an `is` or `get` accessor for boolean properties? Alternatively, I could add a custom rule for every boolean property, but this is not very appealing.

Although the example above is written in Groovy, I've no reason to believe the same behaviour wouldn't be exhibited by the equivalent Java code.

These DTOs are generated by JAXB (which generates an "is" accessor, rather than a "get" accessor for booleans), so I can't rename the accessors. I'm using Dozer 5.3.2.

Comment: Are you using JAXB to generate your DTOs, by any chance?

Comment: yes I am, is there some way you can make it generate get accessors?

Comment: note that Dozer only behaves this way when the `is` method has type `Boolean` - it maps `boolean isFoo()` methods fine.

Answer (score 10):

May be you can use custom getter method to use it.

here s the example  mapping (Write it in dozer-mapping file)

```
<mapping>
  <class-a>ProductDto</class-a>
  <class-b>ProductCommand</class-b>
<field>
  <a get-method="isFoo">foo</a>
  <b>foo</b>
</field>
</mapping>
```

So now dozer will use isFoo instead of predefined getFoo. 
Hope this works for you. :)

Answer (score 7):

Generating "is" methods for the Boolean wrapper class is a bug in JAXB, see [Java Beans, BeanUtils, and the Boolean wrapper class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266531/java-beans-beanutils-and-the-boolean-wrapper-class) and http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-131 for details. Seems to be fixed in jaxb 2.1.13

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in JAXB, the small-b `boolean` should have `isFoo()`. You can either use the -enableIntrospection option with later versions of JAXB, or use the oldish boolean getter xjc plugin http://fisheye5.cenqua.com/browse/~raw,r=MAIN/jaxb2-commons/www/boolean-getter/index.html

Comment: Thanks, any idea where I can find this plugin (the link above doesn't work) and how I use it with the ant `wsimport` task?

Comment: Sorry, messed the link up. Fixed now.

Comment: I'm afraid I was using it with Maven

Comment: I figured out how to integrate it with Ant, but it failed with this error `[java] java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin: Provider org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.BooleanGetter could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException`

Comment: Looks like an ant config issue... can you get any more of the stack trace? Does it work if you use the command line xjc?

Answer (score 0):

There also is another way of achieving the correct dozer mapping (the cleanest in my opinion):

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>ProductDto</class-a>
    <class-b>ProductCommand</class-b>
    <field>
       <a is-accessible=”true”>foo</a>
       <b is-accessible=”true”>foo</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

OR the way already mentioned earlier:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>ProductDto</class-a>
    <class-b>ProductCommand</class-b>
    <field>
       <a get-method=”isFoo”>foo</a>
       <b>foo</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```