# Dozer Boolean Mapping - Generic Method

Tags: java, dozer

I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802797/dozer-boolean-property-mapping) which seems to be the same issue that I am facing.I have around 500 classes and most of these have boolean variables. It will be difficult for me to map each and every boolean variable in XML. Is there simpler way by which this can be done - maybe defining a generic custom converter which applies to all boolean variables and uses java reflection to perform the mapping?

EDIT:

Example Mapping:

Class A

```
private Boolean isPrimary;

public Boolean isPrimary() {
    return isPrimary;
}

public void setPrimary(Boolean theIsPrimary) {
    isPrimary = theIsPrimary;
}
```

Class B

```
protected java.lang.Boolean isPrimary;

public java.lang.Boolean isIsPrimary() {
    return isPrimary;
}

public void setIsPrimary(java.lang.Boolean value) {
    isPrimary = value;
}
```

Comment: Do you have getter and setter methods for your boolean fields?

Comment: Yes , I do. I have edited my post to show an example.

Comment: I don't see the changes. Example would be very useful. :)

Comment: Sorry , added the comment before editing :)

Comment: It it possible for you to change the isPrimary() in classes similar to class A to isIsPrimary() ?

Comment: no , since it is provided by external team and it would be difficult to get them change as it is currently being consumed by other apps.

Comment: Ok. You are using Mapper class for mapping, right? Like mapper.map(objectA, objectB) ?

Comment: Yes , that's correct. Object A and Object B are complex data structures. These contains multiple complex objects and each of these objects have a number of boolean variables defined.

Comment: Why don't you want to use XJC plugin from provided link and solve the root of the problem?